# Why can't I "cat file > /dev/input/event"?

Tags: linux, input, evdev

I'm playing with Linux input events and devices. I wrote a simple toy C program that opens /dev/input/event* and writes [Linux multi-touch events](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt) to the opened file. It worked well and I was able to mimic customer's swipe event. (I know I can use evemu-* for this, but wanted to test with my own code).

But I found that if I try to write recorded events directly to the file in command line shell, it doesn't work with this error. Now I'm wondering why I can't write the events directly to the file. My toy program doesn't do anything special but open a file and write events to it. I think I should be able to do the same thing with cat and redirect. Am I doing something wrong in this command?

```
# cat ./swipe_events > /dev/input/event2
/system/bin/sh: cat: <stdout>: Invalid argument
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check the difference with `strace`. It might be due to write lengths.

Comment: @that-other-guy thanks, I think you're right. I can see the last write syscall returns different length (1312 vs 1319). I'll investigate more with the hint.

`write(1, "\nE: 1616526181.476142 0000 0000 "..., 1319) = 1312
write(1, "0000 0\n", 7)                 = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

vs 

`write(1, "\nE: 1616526181.476142 0000 0000 "..., 1319) = 1319`